# Swagger parameter prefix

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

How I can prefix, to swagger parameter?

```
        Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
               .ignoredParameterTypes(AuthenticationPrincipal.class)
               .globalOperationParameters(Arrays.asList(crsfTokenHeader()))
...

    private Parameter crsfTokenHeader() {
        return new ParameterBuilder()
                .name(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)
                .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
                .parameterType("header")
                .required(false)
                .build();
    }
```

I want add default prefix **"Bearer "**

Comment: Is this Springfox?

Comment: Yes... Spring Fox 2.9.2